# Return JSON with HTML tags in spring rest controller

Tags: html, json, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am returning a json file content from spring rest controller.

```
"templates": {
        "header": "<div class=\"row\"> \n  {%util.eachComponent(components, function(component) { %} \n    <div class=\"col-sm-2\"> \n      {{ component.label }} \n    </div> \n  {% }) %} \n</div>",
        "row": "<div class=\"row\"> \n  {%util.eachComponent(components, function(component) { %} \n    <div class=\"col-sm-2\"> \n      {{ getView(component, row[component.key]) }} \n    </div> \n  {% }) %} \n  <div class=\"col-sm-2\"> \n    <div class=\"btn-group pull-right\"> \n      <div class=\"btn btn-default editRow\">Edit</div> \n      <div class=\"btn btn-danger removeRow\">Delete</div> \n    </div> \n  </div> \n</div>",
        "footer": ""
}
```

My JSON file contains html tags and \n chars. When I see the output \n is converted to new line and html tags are rendered as html which I do not want. Also this

```
"templates": { "header": "
\n {%util.eachComponent(components, function(component) { %} \n
\n {{ component.label }} \n
\n {% }) %} \n
", "row": "
\n {%util.eachComponent(components, function(component) { %} \n
\n {{ getView(component, row[component.key]) }} \n
\n {% }) %} \n
\n
\n
Edit
\n
Delete
\n
\n
\n
", "footer": "" }
```

How do I ensure that the spring controller output treats the html tags and \n chars as simple text?

I am returning the JSON file content as String from my controller.

```
 @GetMapping("/getFile/{fileName}")
 public String getJsonFile(@PathVariable String formName) {
    ...
    String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    return fileContent;
}
```